# Python JSON encoding invalid json format

Tags: python, character-encoding

i've stucked, i have a json with  symbols like `'` in values and syntax with `'` and `"`

Example mix double qoute and single qoute[link](https://repl.it/@RJ10/PowerfulDefiantKernel#main.py)

```
json ={
 'key': "val_'_ue",
 'secondkey': 'value'
}
```

With json loads and json dumps i got a `str` type not a `dict` to iterate, any ideas how i get it fixed?

```
        print(postParams)# = {'csrf-token': "TOKEN_INCLUDES_'_'_symbols", 'param2': 'params2value'}

        jsn_dict2 = json.loads(json.dumps(postParams))
        print(type(jsn_dict2)) # ERROR HERE why str and not dict
        
        for key, val in jsn_dict2.items():
            print("key="+str(key))
```

Comment: `json.loads` converts JSON to Python; `json.dumps` converts Python to JSON. Using both in a chain does not make sense.

Comment: From your comments to the answers it isn't clear whether `res` is actually JSON.  Please [edit] the question to show its contents, or at least enough of it to provide an [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to `dumps()` an already string json data:

```
jsn_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(res))
```

should be :

```
jsn_dict = json.loads(res)
```

**UPDATE**

according to comments the data is looks like so:

```py
postParams = "{'csrf-token': \"TOKEN_INCLUDES_'_'_symbols\", 'add-to-your-blog-submit-button': 'add-to-your-blog-submit-button'}"
```

so i found an library that can help damaged json string like this one:

- first run :

  `pip install demjson`
- then this code can help you:

```
from demjson import decode
data = decode(postParams)
data
>>> {'csrf-token': "TOKEN_INCLUDES_'_'_symbols",
 'add-to-your-blog-submit-button': 'add-to-your-blog-submit-button'}
```

Comment: if i remove the dump i got following error, seems then json loads need doublequotes

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1) `


normaly i woul said I use `str.replace("singelqoute", "doubleqoute"` bot this is no option , i have singelqoutes in my values

Comment: this was only a example this result which produced the error can finde below (outcomment in code above)
`{'csrf-token': "TOKEN_INCLUDES_'_'_symbols", 'param2': 'params2value'}`

Comment: try [link](https://repl.it/@RJ10/PowerfulDefiantKernel#main.py)
the problem is there are double qoutes and single qoutes inmix

Comment: do you changed something, i could not see any change on the link
not sure if you have access to write on repl .it

Answer (score 0):

In your json u have missed the "," comma separation between two keys. The actual structure of the JSON is

json_new ={
'key': "val_'_ue",
'secondkey': 'value'
}

use

```
json_actual=json.dumps(json_new)
```

to read,

```
json_read=json.loads(json_actual)
```

Comment: hi ups i forgot the comma in my example
if i remove the dump i got following error

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1) `

Comment: lol this is exactly what he was trying to do.... he just didnt present his initial json as a string as intended...